# Post json data with php cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to post some data using JSON to an API. This API will generate a token that i will need later to do other requisitions to this API.

This is my code.

```
$data = array("grant_type" => "password", "client_id" => "454665", "client_secret" => "6544465645", "username" => "654164@54484.com", "password" => "5454644", "refresh_token" => "648654");
$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) //<- i was missing this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json'
     //'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
)); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo json_decode($result);
```

The problem is that echo json_decode($result); is returning a blank page, whit no response.

I tested the API in postman and it's returning me a token.
I think I'm just missing something to echo the data correctly.

Comment: You never actually define `$data_string`. Try: `$data_string = json_encode($data);`

Comment: Why would go through the trouble of using curl? I suggest using Guzzle instead, which is a wrapper around curl, but with easier interface functions.

Comment: @Sammitch thanks, i forgot it. But the json_decode($result) continues returning a blank page.

Comment: @Mazzy i will take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: Running the following should give you a bit more data.

    `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));`

Comment: @ctatro85 thank you. It helped me to solve the problem. i was missing the ssl verify peer. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false). I will edit my post whit the missing line.

Comment: check `https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php`   `curl_error` to identify what the actual problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer and expanding upon it:
Running the following should give you a bit more data.
`var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));`

As stated by the original poster, the issue turned out to be the cert was being marked as invalid. More often than not, this is due to the cert being a self-signed cert, but any invalid cert would throw this error.

For development this is acceptable. However, in production you **ALWAYS** want to verify the url you are requesting has a valid cert. This is normally for security reasons.

Adding the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` resolved the issue.